# Boxing captor arduino nano 33 ble : problem excel

Tags: arduino

(sorry for bad english)

I make a project for school : it's a boxing captor made with the Arduino nano 33 ble sense. I only use the accelerometer and gyroscope include on the card. I want to know the acceleration of the boxer's hit in order to deduce the hit power of the boxer. Also the inclinaison of the punching bag will be useful.
The captor will be put on the punching bag.
The simple programm of accelerometer works but when i try to edit it in order to transfer the data excel i have a error message "Error :DATA < ASCII 10 or >ACSII 200 with PLX-DAQ....". I can't fix it..

can you help me please ?

thanks you for your help !!

[the code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNbxd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that PLX-DAQ won't accept ASCII characters < 10 or > 200.

`\t`, horizontal tab is decimal `9`. Make sure you only send characters which are decimal 10-200 in the ASCII table.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

From the PLX-DAQ manual:

> - For simple error checking, PLX-DAQ will indicate an error anytime that
>   a string containing characters < ASCII 10 or > ASCII 200 is received.
> - Values of ASCII 10 (Line Feed) are replaced with ASCII 13 (Carriage
>   Return) prior to processing.

I suggest you use comma instead of horizontal tab to separate the values.

Comment: thank you for your answer ! Indeed,put a comma has fix the error message but when i launch PLX DAQ it is only display a lot of data in columns but it do not draw a graph in real time when i move the card  in order to use the accelerometer inside ...

how can i do that ?

Comment: post a new question with more information